# Angular js item.push is not an object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am trying to push data to an array and display it using ng-repeat but i am getting an error i.e, itemorg.push is not a function and itempeople.push is not a function.    And also i need to make both arrays null after compltion of call because without making null while displaying back all the item getting appended and getting display i mean previous data also getting display

```
$scope.display = function(list, searchid) {
    $scope.Itemsorg = [];
    $scope.Items = [];
    $scope.Itemspeople = [];
    $scope.displayItems = [];
    $scope.Itemsorg = '';
    $scope.Itemspeople = '';
    $scope.Items = '';

    switch (searchid) {

        case 'organisation':

        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
          $scope.Itemsorg.push(list[i].relatedEntityInstanceId);
          $scope.Items = $scope.Itemsorg
          break;

         case 'people':
          if (list.length == 0) {
            $scope.Items = '';

          } else if (list.length > 0) {
            for (var j = 0; j < list.length; j++) {

              $scope.Itemspeople.push(list[j].relatedEntityInstanceId);
              $scope.Items = $scope.Itemspeople;

            }
          }
        }
    }
}
```

what i had made mistake please help me friends

Comment: `$scope.Itemspeople = [];` followed by `$scope.Itemspeople='';`, so it's a string, not an array. `String` does not have a `push` method.

Comment: thanks for the reply then how can i make it work .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In line 6 and 7 of your example, you define `$scope.Itemsorg` and `$scope.Itemspeople` as empty strings. The same goes for `$scope.Items` later in line 8 and 21!

What you probably meant in all those lines are empty arrays:

```
$scope.Itemsorg = [];
$scope.Itemspeople = [];
$scope.Items = []; // etc.
```

Comment: i need to make both arrays null after compltion of call because without making null while displaying back all the item getting appended and getting display i mean previous data also getting display. how can i solve this??

Comment: `''` is not the same as "empty array". `[]` is.